# How connect redux store and input value?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

please advise. I want to connect my input value on store and value input in component. How can I do this and is it even possible to do this

Now when you enter into the input, nothing happens (the string is always empty)

```
 const Search: React.FC = () => {
      const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
      const inputValue = useAppSelector((state) => state.inputSlice.inputValue)
      const changeInputValue = debounce(
        (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
          dispatch(inputChangeValue(e.target.value))
        },
        200
      )

  return (
    <div className={styles.search__wrapp}>
      <input
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => {
          changeInputValue(e)
        }}
        placeholder="Find your favorite character"
        className={styles.search}
      />
      <button className={styles.button__search}>
        <img src={search} alt="search icon" />
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(removeInputField())
        }}
        className={styles.clearInput}
      >
        <img src={closeIcon} alt="inputClear icon" />
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

my redux toolkit slice

```
interface Input {
  inputValue: string
}

const initialState: Input = {
  inputValue: '',
}

export const inputSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'inputValue',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    inputChangeValue: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.inputValue = action.payload
    },
    removeInputField: (state) => {
      state.inputValue = ''
    },
  },
})

export const { inputChangeValue, removeInputField } = inputSlice.actions

export const selectCount = (state: RootState) => state.inputSlice.inputValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you register the `inputValue` reducer to the store like this.

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
   inputValue: inputSlice.reducer
});

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: (state, action) => combinedReducers(state, action)
});
export default store;
```

Then in the `Search` component, replace `inputSlice` into `inputValue` (because you registered as "inputValue" in `combineReducers`), like this

```
const inputValue = useAppSelector((state) => state.inputValue.inputValue)
```